# Struts2 JQuery plugin cannot call split of undefined

Tags: java, ajax, forms, struts2

I kept on receiving this error on my form each time I send an ajax request to the server

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

I am using Struts-Jquery plugin.

Here is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<script 
        language="JavaScript" 
        src="utils.js" 
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script 
        language="JavaScript" 
        src="validation.js" 
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>


<sj:head />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Register for a prize by completing this form.</h3>
    <div id="divErrors"></div>

    <s:form action="register" id="form">
        <label>UserName</label>
        <s:textfield name="userBean.username" />
        <s:fielderror />

        <sj:submit targets = "form" value="AJAX Submit" />
    </s:form>

    <audio  src="x.mp3" controls>Your browser
        does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line throws this error? Can you paste the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

In your submit tag `<sj:submit targets = "form" value="AJAX Submit" />`
you should add the div where you will displaying the result of the action.

Eg.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<s:form action="register" id="form">
    <label>UserName</label>
    <s:textfield name="userBean.username" />
    <s:fielderror />

    <sj:submit targets = "result" value="AJAX Submit" />
</s:form>
```

> Regards,
>   Shailendra